# meta tag should be an empty element tag

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee, meta

I am trying to enter the following meta tag in my jsp page using strut taglib

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" name="Webmaster" content="Telephone: <s:text name="webmaster.phone" /> , email:<s:text name="webmaster.email" />, address:<s:text name="webmaster.mail" />">
```

But a warning is showing that meta tag should be empty element tag. What should I do to solve this problem? Is there any other way to enter the  webmaster information in the meta tag?

Comment: I don't get. Can you explain?

Comment: can you add the full error message?

Comment: It is showing: "Tag(meta) should be an empty-element tag" . Nothing more

Comment: your using eclipse 7.0?

Comment: I am using eclipse kepler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your JSP declare a kind of XHTML `DOCTYPE`, then the `<meta>` tag must be properly closed, as discussed in W3School's [HTML Versus XHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp) tutorial:

> ## XHTML Empty Elements Must Always be Closed
>
> In XHTML, empty elements must always be closed, like this:
>
> ### Correct:
>
> ```html
> A break: <br />
> A horizontal rule: <hr />
> An image: <img src="happy.gif" alt="Happy face" />
> ```
>
> ### Wrong:
>
> ```html
> A break: <br>
> A horizontal rule: <hr>
> An image: <img src="happy.gif" alt="Happy face">
> ```

So your tag should be:

```
<meta 
  http-equiv="Content-Type" 
  content="text/html; 
  ...
  address:<s:text name="webmaster.mail" />"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Eclipse warning in my html code and discovered it's b/c I didn't properly close the meta tag.

Example incorrect meta tag:

```
<meta name="description" content="blah blah">
```

Fixed by properly closing meta tag with "/>" :

```
<meta name="description" content="blah blah"/>
```